# Can i use @CreationTimestamp on an @Embeddable pojo?

Tags: java, hibernate

Can i use @CreationTimestamp on an @Embeddable pojo? I've noticed that the date remains null after adding this class:

```
@Embeddable
public class LaborPeriodChange implements Serializable {

    //@PrePersist

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateChanged;
```

to the elementcollection in `LaborPeriod`.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="laborPeriod_change", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="FK_LaborPeriod"))
@Column(name="laborPeriod_change")
@JsonIgnore
private List<LaborPeriodChange> laborPeriodChanges = new ArrayList<>();
```

So can @CreationTimestamp only be used on @Entity pojo's?